# WPF Button with hot image

Tags: wpf

```
                <Button Margin="10,0,2,0" Width="90" Command="Open">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource tstImage}}"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource tstImage1}}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource tstImage2}}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
```

I would like to create a button support hot image: When the mouse hover on the button, the image changes to another one.
I implement a button instance with above code. But actually I would like to create a template that every button can use this style. It is cumbersome to write the same style for every button.

I think it should like:

```
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Source= normalImage"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Source=hotImage"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Source=disableImage"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

And then use the style like:

```
 <Button command="Open" normalImage="icon1.png" hotImage="icon2.png" disableImage="icon3.png"/>
```

I am a fresher to WPF, I have tried many ways to do that but still stuck in this problem. 
I would like to create a template or style that can apply to every button. The second and third snippet is what I want to achieve. But it not works. In the second snippet, the normalImage,hotImage and disableImage are dynamic paths that can be specified by buttons just as what I wrote in the third snippet. 
Please help. Thanks.

I am trying to use attached-property, but I met another problem:
[Style binding attached-property didn't show up anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373686/style-binding-attached-property-didnt-show-up)

Comment: Please clarify, what is your question? Is there an error? Doesn't it compile etc..

Comment: I would like to create a template or style that can apply to every button. The second and third snippet is what I want to achieve. But it not works.  In the second snippet, the normalImage is a dynamic path that can be specified by a button just as what I wrote in the third snippet.  I do not want a fixed path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it myself by using attached property. It may help others, so I post out my code.

Firstly, create the attached property:

```
class ImageAttached : DependencyObject
{
    public static Image GetNormalImage(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Image)obj.GetValue(NormalImageProperty);
    }

    public static void SetNormalImage(DependencyObject obj, Image value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(NormalImageProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for NormalImage.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("NormalImage", typeof(Image), typeof(ImageAttached), new PropertyMetadata((Image)null));

    public static Image GetHotImage(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Image)obj.GetValue(HotImageProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHotImage(DependencyObject obj, Image value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(HotImageProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HotImage.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HotImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HotImage", typeof(Image), typeof(ImageAttached), new PropertyMetadata((Image)null));


    public static Image GetDisableImage(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Image)obj.GetValue(DisableImageProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDisableImage(DependencyObject obj, Image value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(DisableImageProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DisableImage.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisableImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DisableImage", typeof(Image), typeof(ImageAttached), new PropertyMetadata((Image)null));
}
```

Secondly, create a style target to a button:

```
     <Style x:Key="btnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=(local:ImageAttached.NormalImage), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=(local:ImageAttached.HotImage), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=(local:ImageAttached.DisableImage), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Lastly, use it. e.g:

```
        <Button x:Name="btn1" Click="Button_Click_1" Width="100" Height="48" Style="{DynamicResource btnStyle}"
            local:ImageAttached.NormalImage="{StaticResource tstImage}"
            local:ImageAttached.HotImage="{StaticResource tstImage2}"
            local:ImageAttached.DisableImage="{StaticResource tstImage1}"/>
```